# User Input of COLOR command in batch

Tags: batch-file

I am currently trying to do a very simple script that displays all of the COLOR options to the user using echo to display each option. I am a bit stuck on how I would accept the user input and change the foreground and background color from what the user inputted. Here is what I currently have:

```
echo 0 = Black
echo 8 = Gray
echo 1 = Blue 
echo 9 = Light Blue 
echo 2 = Green 
echo A = Light Green 
echo 3 = Aqua 
echo B = Light Aqua 
echo 4 = Red 
echo C = Light Red 
echo 5 = Purple 
echo D = Light Purple 
echo 6 = Yellow 
echo E = Light Yellow 
echo 7 = White 
echo F = Bright White

SET /P COLOR COLOR="Please choose two colors from the list above and type in the hex value: "

PAUSE
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the input first and then change the color.

```
SET /P COLOR="Please choose two colors from the list above and type in the hex value: "
COLOR %COLOR%
```